# Need Realm Swift for Swift 3.0 not Swift 3.0.1

Tags: realm

I just did a Carthage bootstrap on my project that includes RealmSwift. I'm getting a message that says:

> Module compiled with Swift 3.0.1 cannot be imported into Swift 3.0.

I'm using Xcode 8.0 not Xcode 8.1.  My Carthage file has this:

> github "realm/realm-cocoa"

What should I specify in my Carthage file to get RealSwift for Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Use this command:

```
Carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --no-use-binaries --toolchain com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_0
```